# Paste two text lists (one list a file) into one list separated by semicolon

Tags: linux, unix, concatenation, paste

An example of the process/output would be:

File1:

```
hello
world
```

File2:

```
foo
bar
```

Resulting file after concatenation:

File3:

```
hello;foo
world;bar
```

For a large list of non-predictive text (no-wild cards - but lines are aligned as above).

I cannot figure out how to do this with the paste command under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
paste -d';' File1 File2  >  File3
```

Answer (score 4):

`cat` concatenates by lines (or, more accurately, doesn't care what the contents are).

What you seem to need is something more like `paste`.

```
$ paste -d\; file1 file2
hello;foo
world;bar
```